# Rabbi Eleazar and Rabbi Shimeon in Mishna

Tags: rabbis, mishna

In Mishna, it's current to find that "Rabbi Eleazar and Rabbi Shimeon say", e.g. in Rosh Hashana, Yoma, Shkalim, etc. Sometimes it's Eliezer instead of Eleazar, but it's not probably because they were not together, at the same level.

The first question is who is Rabbi Eleazar here, is he the son of Rabbi Shimeon.

In Ritba Yoma, the Ritba seems to have a different Girsa, "Rabbi Eleazar berabbi Shimeon says". It's seems that the Mishna was written by acronyms and was not clear.

The hypothesis that it's always as the Ritba wrote seems plausible. Is there someone who studied this issue. Is there a global hypothesis regarding this frequently occurring sequence?

Comment: Rosh Hashanah and Shekalim don't really count separately because it's the same machlokes

Comment: In Yoma (5:7), the corresponding passages in Mishnah, Tosefta, Bavli and Yerushalmi all have ור"ש. But interestingly, the Yerushalmi  has אומר instead of (אומרים), and further down in the Yerushalmi's commentary on the Mishnah, we see: טעמא דר' לעזר בי רבי שמעון etc., which apparently refers to the opinion given in the name of ר"א ור"ש in the Mishnah. So maybe the Yerushalmi did originally have ר"א בר"ש but it was changed by copyists to match the version in all the other sources

Comment: but in Shvuot 12a it's sure that that is Rabbi Shimeon regarding the sugia of yoma